# Remove table index by key in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this code

```
if not _elementdata[to] then
    _elementdata[to] = {}
end
if not _elementdata[to][key] then
    _elementdata[to][key] = {}
end
_elementdata[to][key] = { value = value, sync = sync or false }
```

But I have a issue when deleting it from the table.. I use

```
if _elementdata[source] then
    _elementdata[source] = nil
end
```

The first time I enter the game I have no errors, second time that I enter I get this error:

```
table index is nil
```

And if I keep reconnecting the errors increases with the number of reconnects.. so I guess that it's not deleting it at all.. btw here is the code to get the data and sent it to the clients:

```
for to, _ in pairs(_elementdata) do
    for key, _ in pairs(_elementdata[to]) do
        if to == root or _elementdata[to][key].sync then
            triggerClientEvent(source, "onClientElementSync", source, to, key, _elementdata[to][key].value)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What's the value of `source` in `_elementdata[source]`?

Comment: `_elementdata[to]` is the second argument you are getting out of the first `pairs` call (that you are ignoring and assigning to `_`). If you really want to ignore it don't bother with `, _` there at all you don't need it. Alternatively, give it a name and use it instead of re-fetching it out of `_elementdata`. (Unless there is some funny metamethod stuff going on here of course.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Actually I don't know why I did it like that lol, fixing it, ty for pointing that out.

Comment: @YuHao source is a data value sent from the client (it's like the client ID but in userdata value)

Comment: @lhf I use the if to check if the table _elementdata[source] exist, else create it

Comment: `source` has to be `nil` for that error to be triggered; you need to show the code that surrounds that "delete" fragment or check the data you are getting from the client (or the logic that reads and converts the data)